# Modification of a pure state by a unitary on a C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\rho$ be a pure state on $A$ i.e. $\rho\in PS(A)$. Let $\tilde{A}$ be the unitisation of $A$ and $u$ be a unitary element in $\tilde{A}$. If we define $\rho^u:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\rho^u(a)=\rho(uau^*)$. I have to show that $\rho^u$ is also a pure state on $A$.

I know $A$ is a hereditary $C^*$-algebra in it's unitisation $\tilde{A}$, hence the map is well defined. Now for proving that it's a state I have to show somehow that $\operatorname{lim}_{\lambda}\rho^u(u_\lambda)=1$ where $\{u_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$ is an approximate unit of $A$. I do not know how to proceed further.

Any form of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $uu_\lambda u^*$ is another approximate unit.

Comment: @Ruy Can you please give some hint on how to prove this fact?

Comment: $\|(uu_\lambda u^*)a - a\| =  \|u^*(uu_\lambda u^*a - a)u\| =  \|u_\lambda (u^*au) - u^*au\|.$